# Gunpowder Fishing

Tags: sea-of-thieves

While playing Sea of Thieves on a random crew, one of the players mentioned that you can use a gunpowder barrel to blow up a school of fish off the islands. Supposedly this will spawn in several fish that you can then pick up and add to your inventory.

That being said I did some google searches for this, but haven't found any results to confirm this. Can anyone else confirm that this functionality is legit?

Comment: Unless something was added, you never could use gunpowder barrels to fish - schools of fish aren't even a thing as far as I remember.  *You can* find fish in barrels floating in water - I wonder if they meant that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not true.  The fish you see swimming just off of the coast of islands, outposts, and trading posts, etc. are just for visual effect.  You can swim through them without interrupting their movements or disturbing them.  The only ways to get fish are by fishing or finding them in storage crates, rowboats, sunken ships, etc.  You can find many simple guides on which fish require what bait, time of day, or region in order to catch if you look online.